# downloading images from links as column values in a csv file in linux/unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, command-line

I have a temp.csv file that has 4 columns and plenty of rows. The column0 has a link that are images from the internet like 'www.abc.com/one.jpg' and so on. I usually download any link using the following wget command for any single link:

```
wget http://www.sample.com/temp.jpg  -O /home/tempfolder/
```

Is there any way I can use or extend the wget command to download all of the links listed under the column0 of my csv file and save it to a folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this out - wget is unable to save the files. However, here's a fix:

`cut -f1 -d, filename | while read url; do wget ${url} -O /home/tempfolder/$(basename ${url}); done`

I hope this helps.

Comment: why do you have wget${url} and $(basename${url})

Comment: Because wget shouted this out at me:

$ cut -f1 -d, test.csv | while read url; do wget $url -O /tmp; done
/tmp: Is a directory
/tmp: Is a directory

Comment: and basename takes the last name of a directory, in this case the filename for the image.

Comment: It works for some files. But for some I get permission denied message on my console. But the folder is still empty in the end. I don't understand why this happens because it shows downloading for some pictures

Comment: You can use `xargs` to make your life easier without a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -f1 -d, filename | while read url; do wget $url -O /home/tempfolder; done
```

The command:

```
cut -f1 -d, filename
```

"Cuts" field 1 (`-f1`) of lines delimited by commas (`-d,`) from the specified `filename`.

We then pipe that to:

```
while read url
```

Which reads each line coming from `cut` into the variable `url`.

Then we `wget` the specified `url`.

**Edit**: To fix your permissions problems:

```
pushd /home/tempfolder ; cut -f1 -d, filename | while read url; do wget $url; done; popd
```

Comment: This seems pretty convincing @Sean Bright. Can you explain a bit on this though ?

Comment: I tried this. But it gives me permission denied multiple for till the end. Do I need to be a super user to execute the above ?

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you run this script in the same directory as the CSV_FILE or provide a full path to this file.

```
for link in `cat CSV_FILE | cut -d, -f1` 
do
     wget $link -O /home/tempfolder/
done
```

EDIT: You asked me to elaborate. This is a for loop that iterates over each link in that file. The `cat CSV | cut -d, -f1` extracts only the column that holds the links. The for loop iterates over all these links and one by one places them in the variable named `link`. Upon each iteration we perform a wget using that `link` variable. You can either run this on command line, or create a file, add this line at the top: `#!/bin/sh`, and run it using `./file_name`. I hope this is detailed enough.

Comment: Can you elaborate that please ?